# Location for static files (css and js) in spring/maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying reference css and js files in my thymeleaf views in my current spring (not spring-boot) project like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
```

the files are placed inside the directory `/src/main/webapp` of my project, in two directories: `css` and `js`.

When I open the page in the browser, the files are unreacheable. What are the right place to put these files?

ps.: my configuration files are:

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>loja</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**springmvcapp-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.kleber"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value></property>
        <property name="templateMode">
            <value>HTML5</value></property></bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"></property></bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"></property></bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"></property></bean>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name><filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add `<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>` and `<mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>` to `springmvcapp-servlet.xml`.

Comment: @manish I add this and now I am getting 404 page when I try access the webapp in the browser. Besides the two lines added, nothing more was changed in the file as displayed above.

Comment: Check out [my sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-sample) available on Github and then compare with your application to see why you are getting errors.

Comment: @manish i notice you do not have a `*-servlet.xml` file on your sample project, and all your beans and resources are declared on your context xml file `springWebContext,xml`. Can you tell me why you use this approach? I am using the the `*-servlet.xml` file for that declarations? what's the difference between this two approaches?

Comment: `springWebContext.xml` **is** the web context loader file (what you call as `*-servlet.xml`) so there is no difference of approach. Naming convention used in the sample app is simply based on the layer name (`springDataContext.xml`, `springServiceContext.xml`, `springWebContext.xml`, etc.).

Comment: @manish ok, then i solve the 404 page problem, but the application still can't reach the static files. the current code is here: https://github.com/klebermo/store

Comment: You have put `<mvc:resources ...` configuration in the wrong file. That configuration should go into the web context loader configuration, which in your case is declared in `springmvcapp-servlet.xml`. The configuration should therefore go in there.

Comment: @manish I try this, but this way I get the 404 page when I try access the application in the browser.

Comment: The `springmvcapp-servlet.xml` has no configuration that would force the web context loader to discover and initialise controllers. Take a look at [my modified version of your app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42052790). You can run it as `mvn tomcat7:run` to verify that the home page loads fine (with CSS and JS).